# How to validate number.number.number;number this format in Reg ex

Tags: java, regex

My string should contains in this format number.number.number;number ex:15.2.63;4 
How to validate this format in Reg ex. I have done in normal way used contains, spilt etc. But lines of code increased. May I know how do it in reg ex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with this:

```
^\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+;\d+$
```

With a <kbd>[liveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/aM4yD7/2)</kbd>

Comment: What advantage does [] around the dots have?

Comment: @Alexander it match the `.` literally instead of using `\.`

Comment: Yea, I would have used the `\.` Was just wondering if there is a practical difference @Thomas

Comment: @ Thomas I tried with answer but it supports this format 1..1;6 .

Comment: @sasikumar ok, just change the `*` with `+`

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it, here using PCRE:

```
laptop:~$ echo "12.34.56;7" | perl -ne 'print $_ if (/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+;\d+$/);'

12.34.56;7

laptop:~$ echo "12a.34b.56c;7" | perl -ne 'print $_ if (/\d+\.\d+\.\d+;\d+/);'

laptop:~$ echo "12.34.56;7" | perl -ne 'print $_ if (/^(\d+\.){2}\d+;\d+$/);'

12.34.56;7
```

If you know the exact length of each part, you can also fix it.
For example \d{2}. will match 11. but won't match 123.

The above answer group dot into bracket ([.]) this is useless for a single character.
But if you delimiter may vary, you can use, for example [.;-] to allow . ; and - as a delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
^[1-9][\.\d]*[1-9][\.\d]*[1-9][\.\d]*[1-9][\;\d]?$
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This won't validate what the OP stated. e.g: [it matches `1234`](https://regex101.com/r/yK2uF9/1)